# Are the homology groups of complete intersection varieties torsion-free.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth sub-variety of the projective space $\prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}^{n_i}_{\mathbb{C}}$ given as the complete intersection of multi-homogeneous polynomials $\{ f_l \}$. Are the homology groups $H_m(X,\mathbb{Z})$ torsion-free?